# SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want it to count then `if @intcount > 0` it should show data or else no data found, but when I execute it gives me 'no data found' regardless, what am I doing wrong?

```
@FiscalYear int,
@SchoolID int,
@Status int

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @sqlstr varchar(2000)
declare @intCount int
set @intCount = 0

set @sqlstr = 'Select @intCount = Count(*)
              From PrivateSchool left outer join Attachment on  Attachment.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID
              inner join FiscalYearPrivateSchool fp ON  fp.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID 
              Where (FiscalYear = '+convert(varchar, @FiscalYear)+') AND (PrivateSchool.IsActive = 1)'

 IF (@SchoolID != -1)
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND SchoolID ='+ convert(varchar, @SchoolID)

 IF (@Status = -1)
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID'

 Else IF (@Status = 1)
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND Attachment.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID'
 Else 
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND Attachment.PrivateSchoolID is Null'


 If (@intCount > 0)
 BEGIN
 set @sqlstr=   'Select SchoolName as School, 
 (Case when Attachment.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID THEN ''Uploaded''    
  ELSE ''Not Uploaded'' END) AS Status,
  COUNT(Attachment.PrivateSchoolID) AS [Count] 
              From PrivateSchool left outer join Attachment on  Attachment.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID
              inner join FiscalYearPrivateSchool fp ON  fp.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID 
              Where (FiscalYear = '+convert(varchar, @FiscalYear)+') AND (PrivateSchool.IsActive = 1)'



 IF (@SchoolID != -1)
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND SchoolID ='+ convert(varchar, @SchoolID)

 IF (@Status = -1)
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID'

 Else IF (@Status = 1)
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND Attachment.PrivateSchoolID = PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID'
 Else 
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' AND Attachment.PrivateSchoolID is Null'

    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' Group by SchoolName, Attachment.PrivateSchoolID, PrivateSchool.PrivateSchoolID'
    SET @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' Order By SchoolName'
EXEC(@sqlstr)
 END
 ELSE
 Select 'No Data Found' as 'FileUpload'
 END
```

Comment: You do `set @intCount = 0` so `@intCount` will always be `0`.

Comment: As an aside you really don't need to be building dynamic SQL here.

Comment: In addition to avoiding dynamic SQL when possible, I also have this big mindblock when it comes to executing the same query twice, once to see if there are rows, and then once to return rows. Why not just code the consumer to handle an empty result set gracefully, instead of changing the shape of the result and returning a row that says "no data"? This seems quite a lot more complex than it needs to be. In addition, it's also very inefficient to get a count if the actual value doesn't matter - you should look into EXISTS if you want to continue programming this way.

Comment: It's a struct that *can* short-circuit. SQL Server knows it doesn't actually need to return data, and the seek/scan can be a lot cheaper if it doesn't have to inspect every single row, maintain a count, etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstr, N'@intCount INT OUTPUT', @intCount = @intCount OUTPUT;

IF (@intCount > 0)
BEGIN
    ....
END
```

You'll also need to make `@sqlstr NVARCHAR(2000)` and add set it to `N'SELECT ...'` as opposed to `'SELECT ...'` - that leading N can be important.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
declare @intCount int
set @intCount = 0
...
<a bunch of code where @intcount doesn't change>
If (@intCount > 0)
```

It's always going to be 0.

Comment: so I should set @intCount equals to anything?

Comment: @paabobo - see Aaron's answer for a fix.  I was pointing out the logical fallacy in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is one of scope. The EXEC(@sqlstr) command doesn't have access to the @intcount variable in your stored procedure. I would bet if you ran this code in a query window, it would tell you to declare @intcount.

Listen to YUCK and rewrite this to avoid dynamic SQL, and then your SELECT will be able to set the @intcount variable.

Comment: @paabobo: use Aaron's answer. I am right about the scoping problem (just tested it) but Aaron shows you a way to get around it.

Comment: @Aaron : Thank you for your help, im going to try it